# RSS reader error while formatting Date

Tags: android, rss, date-format

So i have a great RSS reader source code, it works perfect, but i have one problem, i need to convert date from Fri, 30 Mar 2012 05:09:20 +0000 to simple format "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss", but i can't make it work, because conflicting two data types, NodeList and Date.

```
public class rssparser {


private static NodeList newdate;

private static NodeList formmatter;
private static NodeList formatter;
private static Intent event;
private static ResourceBundle bundle;
private static NodeList pubdate1;


public static void parse(){
URL url;
try {
    url = new URL("http://www.gaudeamus.fm/feed/");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    if(conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
          DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
          Document doc;
          doc = db.parse(url.openStream());
          doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
          NodeList itemLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");



          arrays.PodcastTitle = new String[itemLst.getLength()];
          arrays.PodcastURL = new String[itemLst.getLength()];
          arrays.PodcastContent = new String[itemLst.getLength()];
          arrays.PodcastMedia = new String[itemLst.getLength()];
          arrays.PodcastPubDate = new String[itemLst.getLength()];

       // SimpleDateFormat pubdate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss");
       // Date formmater = formatter.parse("Sat, 24 Apr 2010 14:01:00 GMT");


          for(int i=0; i < itemLst.getLength(); i++){

                Node item = itemLst.item(i);
                if(item.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element ielem = (Element) item;
                    NodeList title = ielem.getElementsByTagName("title");
                    NodeList link = ielem.getElementsByTagName("link");
                    NodeList pubdate = ielem.getElementsByTagName("pubDate");
                    //NodeList description = ielem.getElementsByTagName("description");
                    NodeList content = ielem.getElementsByTagName("content:encoded");


                     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                     String formatedDate =sdf.parse(pubdate);


                    arrays.PodcastTitle[i] = title.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                        arrays.PodcastTitle[i] +=formatedDate+"  \n" + pubdate.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                        arrays.PodcastURL[i] = link.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                        arrays.PodcastContent[i] = content.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                        arrays.PodcastPubDate[i] = pubdate.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                        //arrays.PodcastMedia[i] = mediaurl;




                }

          }

    }

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (DOMException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}


}
```

This is a code,

`String formatedDate =sdf.parse(pubdate);` but my problem is that parse needs String type, but i have NodeList, i tried a lot of variants, but it won't work. If i make not parse but format like that  `String formatedDate =sdf.format(pubdate);` it doesn't show any error, but when i launch my app, it crash on loading news.

Can someone help me? Sorry for bad English.

Comment: sorry i'm new on java/android. You ask me for logcat messages?

Answer (score 0):

Parse this:

```
arrays.PodcastPubDate[i] = pubdate.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
```

Instead of the `NodeList`? I'm assuming that's a `String`; you can't just parse a `NodeList`, it doesn't make any logical sense.

Answer (score 0):

you not only have XML parsing problem. you also have timeformat parsing problem too

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss Z");
Date formatedDate = sdf.parse(((Node)((Element)pubdate.item(0)).getChildNodes().item(0)).getNodeValue());
```

Comment: thanx, but app crashes anyway

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6151466/Gaudeamus/logcat.txt
I can't add error messages list there , because of too much text, so i add log to text file

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify US format:

```
public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
        this.pubDate = dateFormat.parse(pubDate);

    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        Log.e("MySoft", title);
    }
}
```